# How include code with variable expansions inside a here-doc

Tags: bash, shell-script

Trying to cat inside the file this:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/somefile.name
disks=($(lsblk | grep disk | cut -d " " -f 1 | grep -v │))

for i in "${!disks[@]}"; do
  echo 1024 > /sys/block/${disks[$i]}/queue/nr_requests
  echo 1024 > /sys/block/${disks[$i]}/queue/read_ahead_kb
  blockdev --setra 8192 /dev/${disks[$i]}
done
EOF
```

Once it has done, the `${!disks[@]}` and `${disks[$i]}`converts to blank values:

```
for i in ""; do
  echo 1024 > /sys/block//queue/nr_requests
  echo 1024 > /sys/block//queue/read_ahead_kb
  blockdev --setra 8192 /dev/
done
```

How to prevent that?

Comment: command `lsblk | grep disk | cut -d " " -f 1 | grep -v │` is not correct, it ends with `grep -v |` which means you missed something there

Comment: Yeah, but no issues on that line, it returns correct names of the disks :)

Comment: @αғsнιη if you look closely it's a vertical box character not an ASCII pipe

Comment: Do you have an empty line in your array? Side note: Why don't you use `for d in "${disks[@]}"` why to use the index?

Comment: Also, if a usb is mounted while running this, I guess it will go into your array, do you really want this? What are you doing with this script?

Comment: See also `lsblk -dI8 -noname` to list the top-level devices handled by the `sd` subsystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the word you chose as the label for your here-document to prevent its content from being expanded: e.g. `<<'EOF'` instead of `<<EOF`.

Quoting [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents):

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> [n]<<[-]word
>        here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> [...] If any part of *word* is quoted, the *delimiter* is the result of quote removal on *word*, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.  If *word* is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence `\newline` is ignored, and ‘`\`’ must be used to quote the characters ‘`\`’, ‘`$`’, and ‘`` ` ``’.

Since `EOF` (from `cat <<EOF`) is unquoted in your code, all the expansions in the here-document are performed when `cat` is run. At that point, however, the here-document itself is not *executed*, hence no assignment to `disks` is done and `disks` is expanded to the value it had before the here-document was processed:

```
$ unset disks
$ disks=foo
$ cat <<EOF
> disks=bar
> echo "$disks"
> EOF
disks=bar
echo "foo"
```

Comment: It says that command substitution will be performed then why is disks empty?

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav (Sorry, re-posting). Because the assignment to `disks` is not part of any substitution. The result may seem confusing because command substitutions can include arbitrary code that _is_ executed when substitutions are performed, giving the idea that the code in the here-document is run at that point.